# File search application for mac os x with wildcard support

Tags: macos, search, wildcard, spotlight

Is there any program available for searching files in Mac OS X with wildcard(GLOB) support? I am looking something similar to SearchEverything in Windows??

quicksilver/spotlight/google quick searchbox/alfred app doesn't solve my problem :(

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mdfind for files that have been indexed by Spotlight. To do wildcards you need use the following format:

```
mdfind "kMDItemDisplayName=='*back*'c"
```

You can use this approach as "Raw Queries" in the Finder GUI as well. Example pic below, and see my answer at https://superuser.com/a/491119/66255 for more info.

[image: Raw Query Example]

Answer (score 3):

**When you open the finder, instead of searching in the little box, hit Command+F. This will bring up more options to choose from:**

[image: Searching for files whose type is gz, and whose name contains both 19 and 223]

**There are also more options that are hidden by default. Under the "name/kind" list is the option for "other". This will present you with even more stuff to choose from:**

[image: Additional options]

**Almost kind of overwhelming at how many hidden options there are, and I believe it changes depending on which programs you have installed. BUT, better than the (GUI) alternative I suppose...**

**Hop that helps...**

Answer (score 1):

use the unix find command!

http://www.athabascau.ca/html/depts/compserv/webunit/HOWTO/find.htm

Comment: thanks for the quick response. find works for GLOB search, but the issue is that performance (search in 300gb HD takes minutes with find; SearchEverything in windows takes milliseconds for 500GB ) and exclution/inclution of certain folders issue with find. more over i dont want to open terminal for finding a simple file.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `find`, depending on what you are trying to do you might find the OS X [mdfind](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdfind.1.html) command useful.  It's a command line interface to the metadata-store used by [Spotlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29).

Comment: thanks for the quick response; mdfind works great, very fast and accurate results, only issue is that i could not use GLOB(wildcard) queries. more over GUI would be awesone, i dont want to open terminal everything.

Comment: Then just use the normal Spotlight query window normally found by clicking on the magnifying glass icon in the upper right corner of the OS X menu bar.  In either case, the Spotlight query syntax allows for wildcard-like searches.  See here for details: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html